# How can I make an image pass a high res test?

Tags: graphics, resolution

I am designing a t-shirt online and I am using a source image as a pattern, however when I go to render the finished design it says it cannot proceed as the source image is too low resolution.

I have tried various filters and effects to no avail. Obviously I cannot create detail or resolution that doesn't exist but the image looks fine and I believe that there may be some way to apply texture or sharpening effect to the image that would give it the needed resolution to pass the threshold for rendering.

Does anyone have any ideas on which software or filters I might try to achieve my goal?. Thanks

Comment: Is this an automated check used by this company/site? You can just increase the size of the image and adjust the meta data to be whatever DPI you want (e.g. in GIMP). However, like you suggested, you can't create what was never there, but you should be able to artificially pass that check.

Comment: you can try interpolation, Photoshop has many good interpolation algorithms, these algorithms make the image bigger and then try to calculate the values in pixels that was created, it is better than using mspaint (because it just copy the same pixel many times)

Comment: The statement that you cannot recover what's not there is not exactly true. That's the purpose of [super-resolution](https://paperswithcode.com/task/super-resolution). The idea is usually to learn how images and structures look from other pictures and then use this knowledge to increase the resolution of your input picture.